# Posting site to IIS - cannot find files

Tags: asp.net-web-api, iis-7.5

I have created a small site, on IIS express all is working fine. I have created on IIS new application and deployed the package to the folder. the server side is asp.net webapi. the bundle configuration is loading fine when i try to enter the home page, how ever the java script files which are referenced on the cshtml page cannot be found

```
<script src="~/Client/lib/require/require.js" data-main="../../Client/app/requireConfig"></script>
```

i am getting - 
require.js
/Client/lib/require --> 404 cannot be found

and the bundle which works
viewingPanelDirective.js
/NGWeb/Client/app/appComponents/viewingPanel

how can I over come it?

Answer (score 0):

I think i know what might be the cause, i had the same problem myself

in you visualstudio, the js file was running on a url like this

```
http://localhost:/client/lib/require/require.js
```

now you published it, and added it as an application to your default site, you would have given it an alias  (e.g) "testsite"

meaning that in reality the file is hosted at

```
http://localhost/testsite/client/lib/require.js
```

but in reality your site is looking for it (because of the ~) at

```
http://localhost/client/lib etc etc
```

Edit in response to comment:

rather than removing the ~ (which you will  need to navigate you back to the url root), i would rather just include your app name in the bundles virtual path, like this:

```
bundles.Add(new styleBundle("~/yourAppName/Content/css")) ....... etc
```

I also came across this post, I haven't tried it myself but it seems an interesting alternative to my method.

[Fixing Relative CSS Paths when using .NET MVC 4 Bundling](http://thoughtstuff.co.uk/2013/02/fixing-relative-css-paths-when-using-net-mvc-4-bundling/)

Comment: but when i am debugging it - it is using iis express which dont have the app name

Comment: "#if DEBUG" to jump into a different declaration.  You can have different paths for debug vs release. Our config the path in your Web.config